# Application Putty starts in small window

Tags: window, putty

When I launch putty and connect to a device, the window starts in the top right of my screen in a small window and I have to move it and expand it every single time. How can I change it so that when I ssh to a device using putty, the window appears larger, and centralized?

Comment: Why don't you use a standard terminal of the OS?

Answer (score 0):

Change the fontsize. Also do not forget to save it with the connection you want to make otherwise you will need to do this every time.

[image]

will show ...

[image]

and

[image]

will make it a lot larger ...

[image]

Comment: Hey, I tested this and it kind of works, just it's not quite what I was wanting to achieve. So I like the font being small, it's just the window size I'm trying to adjust upon the session to the router. The default window size is really small. I rooted around the options within Putty but i can't seem to adjust it unless I wait for the window to launch, and then adjust it. Which is a nightmare if I have to do that every time.  I need a larger default window size.

Comment: I get what you want but I do not believe I ever saw that happen. The fonts and size are connected (and I do not see an option to disconnect those and have the larger screen size).

Comment: Did you compress these images in the 1980s?